# C language prototype creation

Tags: c, function, prototype

I have this block of code. I have to move the given function `display_name()` into another `.c` file, compile it, and find the error that was caused due to the migration of the function and correct it by creating a header file with a prototype. How can I do it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char student[]="Rasmus Lerdorf";

void display_name()
{
    printf("Student Name : %s",student);
}

int main()
{ 
    display_name();
}
```

these are the changes i made but again i still get an error in the `main.cpp`. it doesnt allow me to include the `displayname.h` file.

**displayname.h**

`void display_name(void);`

**displayname.cpp**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "displayname.h"

char student[] = "Rasmus Lerdorf";

void display_name()
{
    printf("Student Name : %s", student);
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "displayname.h"


int main()
{ 
    display_name();

}
```

errors are:

```
3   IntelliSense: identifier "display_name" is undefined    c:\Users\konstantinos\Desktop\main\main.cpp 7   2   Cproject
2   IntelliSense: cannot open source file "displayname.h"   c:\Users\konstantinos\Desktop\main\main.cpp 2   1   Cproject
Error   1   error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'displayname.h': No such file or directory   c:\users\konstantinos\desktop\main\main.cpp 2   1   Cproject
```

Comment: Show us how you tried to move it and what the error was.

Comment: Note that the suffix `.cpp` usually indicates a C++ source file and very seldom if ever a C source file.  Which language are you using?

Comment: Create a header `display.h`; put the prototype declaration of `display()` in it.  Add `#include "display.h"` to the two source files.  Compile the two source files separately and link the object files together.  Incidentally, your code does not need either `<ctype.h>` or `<string.h>`.

Comment: im using visual studio 2013 and the C language!

Comment: If you're using C, use the source suffix `.c` and not `.cpp`.  If you use `.cpp`, it is likely that the compiler will treat it as C++ rather than C.  Good C code can be compiled by a C++ compiler, but it isn't good C++ code.

Comment: i do not know how to make the declaration of the prototype. this is what im trying to do, plus how can i link them together? through just #include?

Comment: A prototype declaration in C will look like: `extern void display_name(void);` — though the `extern` is optional.  In C++, the equivalent is `extern void display_name();` — but that has a very different meaning in C.  You create `main.obj` from `main.c` and you create `display.obj` from `display.c`; then you create `display.exe` by linking `main.obj` and `display.obj` together.  The header is used when the `.obj` files are created.

Comment: You need to configure your compiler so that it finds your `displayname.h` file. On most compilers (e.g. [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) or [Clang/LLVM](http://clang.llvm.org/)...) it means adding the good `-I` *directory* option

Comment: but how am i supposed to do that? on the other hand if it is what you say, it would'n find the `displayname.h` file as well in the `displayname.cpp` right? but that file finds it. the problem is with the `main.cpp`

Comment: Are `displayname.h` and `displayname.cpp` in the same directory as `main.cpp`?  If not, you are (1) making life unnecessarily difficult for yourself and (2) you must tell the compiler where to find the header.  If they are all in the same directory, you will have to look at the compiler command lines to see what's different.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler im using Visual Studio 2013 and yes i have the files `main.cpp`and `displayanme.cpp` in the Source files of the Solution Explorer and the displayame.h on the header files of the Solution Explorer. i put it in the Source files as well just in case but nothing changed.

Comment: You are getting into details of the UI of the MSVS IDE.  I don't know that UI at all and can't help.  My suspicion is you have the display name code in 'c:\Users\konstantinos\Desktop\displayname` directory (instead of `"…\main`).  That complicates your life. For someone who knows the IDE, it is easy to fix.  I don't know the IDE so I can't help. If the display name code is also in `…\main`, I am bemused, but you need to look at the two compiler command lines to work out what's different and fix the difference.  Again, that requires knowledge of the IDE that I don't have.

Comment: hmm..i see @JonathanLeffler! thanks for your help anyway. i will look at it again later! and i will post. thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prototype functions work like this: for each set of functions that you write (except `main`) you need a **definition** and an **implementation**. Definitions are usually stored in header files (extension `.h`) whereas implementations are stored in source files (extension `.c`).

Here is an example of how you could arrange your code to solve your problem.

Definition: **display.h**

```
// This file contains the definitions of the functions which you want to call from another file
void display_name(void);
```

Implementation: **display.c**

```
#include "display.h"
#include <stdio.h>
static char student[]="Rasmus Lerdorf";
void display_name()
{   printf("Student Name : %s",student);
}
```

With both the definition defined and the desired implemented, now you can call the function from your main source file.

Implementation: **main.c**

```
#include "display.h"
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{ 
    display_name();
}
```

This is how you link together a prototype of a function and the implementation of a function. You can expand this by adding more prototypes to `display.h`, implementing those prototyped functions in `display.c`, and then calling them throughout your code.

To build, both of these `.c` files must be included in your build phase. If you build from the command line, you need to do something like this (I'm assuming that your compiler is `gcc`):

```
cc display.c main.c -o program
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This code too suffers from a non-prototype function declaration.  The declaration in the header is not a prototype declaration in C (though it is in C++).  You must include the `void` in the argument list (`void display_name(void)`) to make it a prototype declaration.  As it stands, it is just a declaration of a function that takes an arbitrary number of arguments — the only thing you know is that it is not a varargs function.

Comment: There's no real reason to declare `student` in the header; there's no code outside of `display.c` that uses it.  In fact, it should be made `static` until there's a proven need to access the variable from outside the source file it is defined in.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler An oversight, thanks. I'll correct it.

Comment: i will tried out the examples guys and i will let u know. thanks a lot for your time!

Comment: @JonathanLeffler i did some changes on the first section of my question. from the original file to the separated files. but i still get an error when i include the file `displayname.h` in the `main.cpp`

Answer (score 2):

Your header file, let's call it `displayname.h` should contain the declaration:

```
void display_name(void);
```

It's usually also best to create an include guard, which avoids causing problems if a header is included more than once:

```
#ifndef DISPLAYNAME_H
#define DISPLAYNAME_H

void display_name(void);

#endif /* DISPLAYNAME_H */
```

Then, in your `displayname.c`, you would include that header plus any others needed by the function, and define your constant and the function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "displayname.h"

char student[]="Rasmus Lerdorf";

void display_name()
{
   printf("Student Name : %s",student);
}
```

And in your `main.c`, you would also include that header:

```
#include "displayname.h"

int main()
{
    display_name();
    return 0;
}
```

I don't know what compiler you are using, but if you're on a Unix-like system (Linux, Mac OS X, or something like msys or Cygwin under Windows), you would compile and link them as follows (you can replace `cc` with your specific compiler, such as `gcc` or `clang`, though on most systems `cc` should exist and point to the default compiler for that system):

```
cc -c -o displayname.o displayname.c
cc -c -o main.o main.c
cc -o myprogram main.o displayname.o
```

You could also abbreviate this as:

```
cc -o myprogram main.c displayname.c
```

I also recommend, when you are learning, to use the `-Wall -Wextra -Werror` flags, to give you as many warnings as possible, and not allow compilation to proceed if there are any warnings. To make this more convenient, so you don't have to type the whole command every time, you can define a simple `Makefile`; the following uses GNU make syntax, if you don't have GNU make let me know and I'll edit it to use a more portable syntax:

```
CFLAGS=-Wall -Wextra -Werror

myprogram: main.o displayname.o
    cc -o $@ $^

%.o: %.c
    cc -c $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<

main.o: displayname.h
displayname.o: displayname.h
```

If you have this set up, you can just type `make` and it will recompile everything that it needs to.

**edit**: I see now from your comments that you are using Visual Studio, so the above tips on how to compile and link using `cc` and `make` are not relevant to you. It has been too long since I have used Visual Studio to walk you through that myself, but Microsoft has a reasonable [walkthrough of how to create and build a project](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384847.aspx) that you can follow. The tutorial is for C++, but it should work similarly for C, just keep in mind that files should be named `.c` if they are written in C, and only `.cpp` if they are written in C++.

Comment: The declaration in the header is not a prototype declaration in C (though it is in C++).  You must include the `void` in the argument list (`void display_name(void)`) to make it a prototype declaration.  As it stands, it is just a declaration of a function that takes an arbitrary number of arguments — the only thing you know is that it is not a varargs function.

Comment: `#pragma once` is a better option than an include guard on some compilers.

Comment: @SevenBits: `#ifdef` has to work in every compiler; `#pragma` once is inherently compiler-specific.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Apologies, fixed.

Comment: @SevenBits As @JonathanLeffler mentions, include guards work everywhere, they are much more portable than `#pragma once`.

Comment: @BrianCampbell I agree with you, and I'm not criticizing your decision. I'm just suggesting a more succinct alternative which works on certain compilers, that's all. :)

Answer (score 0):

i did what you said! i created the 3 specific files `displayname.h` for the prototype , `displayname.cpp` in which the function `display_name()` stays  and `main.cpp` in which i call the function `display_name()`. the problem again is that when i include the file `displayname.h` in the `displayname.cpp` it works fine, but when i include it in the `main.cpp` i have an underline error in the include. what is wrong?

Comment: Edit your own question (or ask a new one) instead of adding an answer. Show the source code and the compilation commands. Give the exact error messages. You probably made a typo.

Comment: i did some changes in the first block of code. the first part is the original file and then i have my changes as i described plus the errors. i hope i mentioned them with a proper way.@BasileStarynkevitch